# Как добавить команды в меню Buttom sheet (copy,insert,eras....)?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin последняя версия.
Сделал buttom sheet с меню.
Вопрос:как определить на них событие - копирование,вставка, удаление ?
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: А вы о чем вообще? Android, desktop, web? Котлин сам по себе, какой бы он не был версии, не содержит никаких bottom sheet или меню или еще каких UI элементов. Молоток понятия не имеет какие им гвозди и куда будут забивать.

Comment: Android. Как на андройде можно задействовать меню копирование, вставка, уадление? Какие команды ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste

Comment: Eugene Krivenja то что надо. Спасибо большое.